# Proper way to update ListView with data?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, parse-platform

I am using ParseQueryAdapter like so:

```
public class MyPostedSalesAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<Sale> {

    static String mTAG = "LocalSalesAdapter";
    static ParseUser mCurrentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

    public MyPostedSalesAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<Sale>() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            public ParseQuery<Sale> create() {
                @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
                ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Sales"); 
                query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
                query.whereEqualTo("postedBy", mCurrentUser.getUsername());
                try {
                    int salesAmount = query.count();
                     ProfileActivity.setTextView(salesAmount);
                } catch (ParseException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
                return query;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public View getItemView(Sale sale, View v, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (v == null) {
            v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.listview_cell, null);
        }

        super.getItemView(sale, v, parent);

        ParseImageView saleImage = (ParseImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        ParseFile photoFile = sale.getParseFile("photo");
        if (photoFile != null) {
            saleImage.setParseFile(photoFile);
            saleImage.loadInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {

                }
            });
        } else { 
            // Clear ParseImageView if the object has no photo, set placeholder.
            saleImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.placeholder); 
        }
        TextView titleTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView_listView_saleTitle);
        titleTextView.setText(sale.getSaleTitle());

        TextView priceTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView_listView_salePrice);
        priceTextView.setText(sale.getSalePrice());
        return v;
    }

}
```

And simply onResume, setting the adapter to ListView like so:

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        mCurrentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

        // Setting up currentUser to current logged in user
        // If user is not logged in, present them with Login Activity
        if (mCurrentUser == null || !isUserOnline())
        {
            presentUserWithLogin();

        }
        else
        {
        mOwnSalesAdapter = new MyPostedSalesAdapter(this);
    mOwnSalesAdapter.loadObjects();
    mUserSales.setAdapter(mOwnSalesAdapter);
}
}
```

I did this onResume, thinking every time the Activity is loaded, new data is pulled using query and displayed in the ListView. However this is not the case, and occasionally will act like this. Normally I have to close the entire app for the ListView to update properly and display any updates to the data. Even If I were to logout of the current parse user, and login on another account without closing the app, the previous user's posts sometimes appear as well in the listview. What am I doing wrong? I never encountered such problems with working in iOS. Also noticed if I were to delete an Item from Parse and go back, usually the item still appears in the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

Hi just call in onResume()

```
if(mOwnSalesAdapter!=null)
   mOwnSalesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```